# How to stop Wine from assigning drive letters to mounted devices automatically?

Tags: filesystems, wine, automounting

Every time I attach a USB drive while or before running a Windows application with Wine, Wine notices it and adds a drive letter for it automatically. I would like to disable this feature in favour of 100% manual wine drive letters management. How can this possibly be done?

Answer (score 2):

I was curious about this too, I found [an answer that works from the WineHQ forums](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=26157#p104880) but I have augmented it a bit:

1. Run winecfg
2. Go to the Drives tab
3. Remove/Add all the drives you do not/do want (ie. in my case I only wanted C:)
4. Go to the Libraries tab
5. Type winedevice.exe in the New override box
6. Click Add
7. Select winedevice.exe from the Existing overrides box and click Edit
8. Select Disable and click Okay on the popup dialog
9. Click Okay on the Libraries tab

When you next load up winecfg the Drives tab should give an error message about not working. I've not looked in to it, but I imagine the winedevice.exe is the service that automatically adds in the drives and that winecfg talks to for the Drives tab, hence the error.

Comment: Disabling winedevice.exe somehow breaks querying network adapters via `GetAdaptersAddresses()`

Answer (score 0):

i use a script to fill all drive letters and comx, run it in your prefix/dosdevices folder, winedevice doesn't create new drive letter if all are occupied and it will have dummy com ports if you don't want it to populate dosdevices folder:

```
touch {a..z}{:,::}
mkdir -p com{1..40}
```